# laravel orm: different result from almost same query

Tags: php, json, laravel, orm

I've a very big doubt about how works laravel for a very simple thing:

If I call:

```
$companies=User::All();
```

Then I can use statement like this in a `forach`:

```
foreach($companies as $company)
$company['new_field']= 'something';
```

If i'm limiting the output of the query like:

```
$companies = DB::table('companies')
            ->select('id','name','email','business_name',...)->get();
```

The things doesnt work as before,

- I try with or without the `->get()`
- I try to convert with `->toArray()` (errors rised)
- I try with `put() and push()` for collections method and agains errors...

How can I add a field in every item of the collection just to pass it to a view?

Comment: I Wouldn't of thought that the User modal uses the companies table, unless it's been changed.. and if so it shouldn't be called users

Comment: yes the model is custom! all is ok  about that!

Comment: do want to use custom attribute in it

Answer (score 2):

Try like this, hope it works for you:

```
$users=User::select('id','name','email','business_name',...)->get()->toArray();
```

and then use foreach loop like this:

```
foreach($users as $key => $value ){
    $users[$key]['newField'] = "Demo";
}
```

Comment: what is the part  $key => $value for?

Comment: if im using the select as u describe without the toArray part I can add a field like before simpli by access $company['new_fiel']=something!

Comment: @JahStation You can remove `$key => $value` part .It's my general practice that I use.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Laravel and model in it so there is a better way to add custom attribute or field here is what i do for custom field

For Example :

There is a Model Name **User**
so in User Model
add a property name appends like :

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $appends = ['new_field'];

    public function getNewFieldAttribute() // defining field logic here
    {
        return // your code
    }
```

So you no need to use foreach and looping and adding new field

for more have a look on laravel doc : https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

> Suggestion

you can limit your output with Model too.

```
User::select('id','name','email','business_name',...)->get();
```

if you are making an array like

```
User::select('id','name','email','business_name',...)->get()->toArray();
```

so this will also give you your custom field

Comment: thanks i've seen this approach but i need more a quick way to pass as just one object things encapsulated in a collection and the field depends from another query...